# John the Ripper. How limit CPU with CGroup

Tags: server, 20.04, cgroup

I want limit CPU at John by CGroup.

I did.

cgrules.conf:

```
*:john      cpu     cpu_1
```

cgred.conf:

```
group cpu_1 {
        perm {
                task {
                        uid = root;
                        gid = root;
                }
                admin {
                        uid = root;
                        gid = root;
                }
        }
        cpu {
                cpu.cfs_period_us=100000;
                cpu.cfs_quota_us=150000;
        }
}
```

However John use all resources of CPU.

It strange for me. But another app was limited. I.e. I think CGroup is worked. But it don't work with John.

I install John via Snap.

If it's possible at all.

Comment: Does `OMP_NUM_THREAD=1 command-to-execute-the-program` work?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi How can I check it? May be it help - `John the Ripper 1.9.0-jumbo-1 OMP [linux-gnu 64-bit x86_64 AVX2 AC]`. My version of John.

Comment: You can check cpu consumption with system monitor. I don't know the command to execute this program. How do you execute it?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I use `htop`. All of 4 CPU is 100%. `john --test` command line.

Comment: Ok, use the command `OMP_NUM_THREAD=1 john --test`, and check it with `htop`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi All the same. :(